# Create dynamic new-object checkbox variables from an array, list or hash

Tags: powershell, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am trying to create check box form/popup that uses a list of PC names that eventually will be passed to the function. Right now I have hard coded the array/list. I want to pop-up a multiple check list that will then based on the input run the script on the PCs that where selected. I'm going to do another test to signify if the PC is online and "pre" check that PC. I'm having issues creating the checkboxes dynamically.

```
cls

function GenerateForm {

#param (
#   [Object] $PCNames = $null   
#)

$PCNames = @("PC1","PC2","PC3")

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$listBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

foreach ($checkBox in $PCNames) {
    $checkBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
}
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$b1= $false
$b2= $false
$b3= $false

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------

$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    $listBox1.Items.Clear();

    foreach ($checkBox in $PCNames) {

    if ($checkBox.Checked)     {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "$checkBox is checked"  ) }

    if ( !$checkBox.Checked) {   $listBox1.Items.Add("No CheckBox selected....")} 

    }
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "Primal Form"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 450
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 236
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$button1.TabIndex = 4
$button1.Name = "button1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$button1.Text = "Run Script"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 156
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button1.add_Click($handler_button1_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($button1)

$listBox1.FormattingEnabled = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 301
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 212
$listBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$listBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$listBox1.Name = "listBox1"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 137
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 13
$listBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$listBox1.TabIndex = 3

$form1.Controls.Add($listBox1)


#$checkBox3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
#$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
#$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
#$checkBox3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
#$checkBox3.TabIndex = 2
#$checkBox3.Text = "CheckBox 3"
#$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
#$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
#$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 75
#$checkBox3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
#$checkBox3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
#$checkBox3.Name = "checkBox3"
#
#$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox3)
#
#
#$checkBox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
#$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
#$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
#$checkBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
#$checkBox2.TabIndex = 1
#$checkBox2.Text = "CheckBox 2"
#$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
#$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
#$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 44
#$checkBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
#$checkBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
#$checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2"
#
#$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox2)


foreach ($checkBox in $PCNames) {
    $checkBox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
    $checkBox.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $checkBox.TabIndex = 0
    $checkBox.Text = "$checkBox"
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 13
    $checkBox.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $checkBox.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $checkBox.Name = "$checkBox"

$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox)
}

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

GenerateForm
```

The errors I am getting:

```
The property 'UseVisualStyleBackColor' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:129 char:5
+     $checkBox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Size' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:133 char:5
+     $checkBox.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'TabIndex' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:134 char:5
+     $checkBox.TabIndex = 0
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:135 char:5
+     $checkBox.Text = "$checkBox"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Location' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:139 char:5
+     $checkBox.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:140 char:5
+     $checkBox.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:141 char:5
+     $checkBox.Name = "$checkBox"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'UseVisualStyleBackColor' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:129 char:5
+     $checkBox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Size' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:133 char:5
+     $checkBox.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'TabIndex' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:134 char:5
+     $checkBox.TabIndex = 0
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:135 char:5
+     $checkBox.Text = "$checkBox"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Location' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:139 char:5
+     $checkBox.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:140 char:5
+     $checkBox.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:141 char:5
+     $checkBox.Name = "$checkBox"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'UseVisualStyleBackColor' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:129 char:5
+     $checkBox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Size' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:133 char:5
+     $checkBox.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'TabIndex' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:134 char:5
+     $checkBox.TabIndex = 0
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:135 char:5
+     $checkBox.Text = "$checkBox"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'Location' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:139 char:5
+     $checkBox.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

The property 'DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:140 char:5
+     $checkBox.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\CheckBox.ps1:141 char:5
+     $checkBox.Name = "$checkBox"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that´s because you redefine the `$checkbox` variable in your `foreach` loop. Here´s a little explanation:

```
$checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox

...

#at this point $checkbox becomes a string (one of your array items):
foreach($checkbox in $pcnames){ 
$checkBox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True #fails because String object doesnt have the property
...
}
```

You can fix this by just using another variable name in your foreach loop.

Also this makes zero sense:

```
foreach ($checkBox in $PCNames) {
$checkBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
}
```

Here you are just redefining $checkbox once for every item in your array, you should just create it in the loop where you assign it its properties